# Aggregating Price using IFERROR/SUMIF

Tags: excel, excel-formula

**Problem**
Unable to sum prices for different part numbers using the combo of formula mentioned below

**What Am I Trying To Accomplish?**
I am trying to sum up prices for various part numbers in a different sheet. They are in millions

**My Formula**
I am using a combination of IFERROR and SUMIF

[image: Sheet1]

[image: Sheet2]

**What my desired result should look like**
[image: Desired Result]

**Note**
When using the combo of IFERROR and SUMIF I am considering both Part num and ALT Part so that if either of the two exists, it should sum the price for both

Thanks

Comment: Is it resolved now?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you may try using `SUMPRODUCT()` Function,

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

• Formula used in cell `C2`

```
=SUMPRODUCT((--ISNUMBER(MATCH($G$2:$G$9,A2:B2,0)))*($F$2:$F$9))
```

---

To explain the above Formula.

• We are using `MATCH()` Function to find the positions of the both Part Numbers in the range `G2:G9`

```
=MATCH($G$2:$G$9,A2:B2,0)
```

The above on evaluating returns

```
{1;#N/A;#N/A;#N/A;2;#N/A;#N/A;#N/A}
```

• Next we are wrapping this within an `ISNUMBER()` Function to exclude the `#N/A` and to take only numbers.

```
ISNUMBER(MATCH($G$2:$G$9,A2:B2,0))
```

Which returns

```
{TRUE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;TRUE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE}
```

• Using double unary to convert the Boolean values to 1's and 0's

```
{1;0;0;0;1;0;0;0}
```

• Next we are then doing a matrix multiplication of the 1's with the corresponding range i.e. `F2:F9`

```
(--ISNUMBER(MATCH($G$2:$G$9,A2:B2,0)))*($F$2:$F$9)
```

Which returns,

```
{5000;0;0;0;5000;0;0;0}
```

• Lastly we wrapping the whole within an `SUMPRODUCT()` Function to get the SUM

```
=SUMPRODUCT((--ISNUMBER(MATCH($G$2:$G$9,A2:B2,0)))*($F$2:$F$9))
```

---

Hence we are not using and `IFERROR()` here since `IFERROR()` function is relatively inefficient and makes calculations slow, if there was no option then we could have used it perhaps when there is way why not use the formula as shown in the screenshot.

Also note to change the ranges in the formulas as per your suit.

---

Answer (score 0):

If I’m understanding this right, the formula you are probably looking for is
=iferror(sumif1,0)+iferror(sumif2),0)

Comment: I was doing more like IFERROR(SUMIF(), SUMIF()). Let me give that a try